Derivative wrt retarded time
I am confused by the following statement in footnote of Griffiths 4th edition (page 446):
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t_r} = \frac{\partial }{\partial  t},$$ where $$t_r=t - \frac{\mathscr{r}}{c}$$ since $\mathscr r$ is independent of time. Here $$\mathscr r=|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'}|.$$
My confusion is that for a moving charge $\boldsymbol{r'} \equiv \boldsymbol{r
'}(t)$. So, how can $\mathscr{r}$ be independent of time? In fact, the expression for $\dfrac{\partial t_r}{ \partial t}$ can be found at here and is not equal to one. So, why has Griffiths assumed  $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t_r} = \dfrac{\partial }{\partial  t}$? Also this question has been asked before, but I did not understand the answer.

Did you mean \mathscr{r} i.e. $\mathscr{r}$?

Can you be more clear on where you're confusion in the answer is? As it is it's less likely to gain positive attention if you don't try and make it clear how you didn't understand the related answer.

Yes, I meant \mathscr{r}. In the link here the expression for $\frac{\partial t_r}{\partial t}$
has been evaluated to 1(1−̂ ′/)
(at the bottom of page).  The same expression can also be found in Schwartz book on Principles of Electrodynamics (equation 6-3-2). Here again partial derivatives of $t_r$ wrt
has been calculated and the answer is not one. (or is it that the expression in Schwartz also should be a total derivative).

Note that the derivatives in Griffiths are partial derivatives i.e. $\mathscr r$ is kept constant, so $\dfrac {\partial t_r} {\partial t} = 1$.
In both the answers you link to the calculated derivative is not $\dfrac {\partial t_r}{\partial t}$, it is $ \dfrac {dt_r}{dt}$ (or, equivalently, $\dfrac {dt}{dt_r}$), and
$ \dfrac {dt_r}{dt} \ne \dfrac {\partial t_r}{\partial t}$.
